# How to make Google authentication page fit in my webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, facebook, webbrowser-control, google-authentication

Windows.Forms.Webbrowser to display the google authentication screen.
The Webbrowser control is in a window of size 450x480 pxl and it fill the whole window.
I am calling:

```
String UrlString = String.Format(
              @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"+
              @"display=popup" +
              @"&scope=email profile" +
              @"&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto" +
              @"&response_type=code"+
              @"&client_id=xxxx
            );
_webBrowser.Navigate(UrlString);
```

The page I get is too big for the Webbrowser control so it places Horizontal and vertical scrollbers.
When I use the 'display=popup' in the facebook authentication page it renders without scrollbars.
Is it possible to get Google authentication page fit in my webbrowser control?

Comment: Thanks Soner for the correction in formatting the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

On document load complete event you can invoke an eval javascript code that returns the height and width of the page. From here you set the width and height of the control based on this values.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I actually need the other way around i.e. I want the page render to the original size of my webbrowser and not the webbrowser to fit itself to the page dimentions.
I also tried using a different user agent like of a mobile device web browser but that didn't help either.

Comment: As I mentioned, Facebook authentication url: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth does respect the display=popup parameter and does the job. Why doesn't Google?

Comment: Then invoke an eval javascript that will set the height and width of the document.